# Sharepoint Online User Pictures

Tags: 2013, user-profile, picture

As the admin of a office 365 subscription with Sharepoint Online

Is it possible for me to place users profile pictures or remove them if inappropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Exchange Online as well, you can use Powershell 
 [Set-UserPhoto](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj218694(v=exchg.150).aspx). The cmdlet works for both on-premise and online.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible. Here is a link:

http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/148/p/173261/505321.aspx?ss=5b31d473-26f2-41da-8c36-9397d1d2fad2#505321

Comment: BOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO (thanks for the answer)

Comment: yea, pretty stupid. I've been finding that out a lot about features you'd just expect to exist.